# How to perform file copying in multiple threads or processor in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, shutil

I"m trying to copy files in python , it'll take long time in sequential approach so I wanted to do it in multiple threads. Below is my code to copy files in sequential

```
for file in files:
    shutil.copy(file,destination_path)
```

this took around 1.2 sec to complete
I tried to implement multithreading as below

```
import multiprocessing
copy_instance(src,dest):
    shutil.copy(src,dest)
for file in files:
    p1 = multiprocessing.process(target=copy_instance,args=(file,destination_path)
    p1.start()
```

this took 168.8 sec to complete

Doing it in multiprocessing taking way more time then sequential approach , what am I doing wrong? how can I correctly implement multithreading to speed up my copying process? any help or suggestion on this will be very helpful, thanks

Comment: Copying is almost certainly bound by storage access time, unless you are copying to and from a ramdisk: parallelisation is unlikely to help.

Comment: You are not multithreading but multiprocessing. It can be *much* slower, more if you are running windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spawning new processes is slow, particularly in windows. Instead of multiprocessing you should use multithreading, which in CPython can be good for I/O (and *is* bad for CPU bound processes):

```py
import shutil
import itertools
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def copy_instance(args):
    shutil.copy(*args)
    
#   ... snipped definition of files and destination

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    pool.map(copy_instance, zip(files, itertools.repeat(destination)))
```

Nevertheless, as noted in the comments, depending on you storage you probably won't see any difference.